# unwanted javascript injection into html

Tags: javascript, html

Previously I bought a template to work on, after polishing and remove unwanted scripts and styles, I started working on that template; Only recently I found out that 1 script appears at the end of the page - after body tag and before end html tag. The script is as follows:

```
script src="http://i.74055djs.info/opt_1380793200421/opt_content.js?partner=74055d&amp;channel=74055dp952&amp;appTitle=" type="application/x-javascript"

/** See http://www.dealply.com/ for details. *//* JavaScriptJsTagUrl = DealPlyScriptTagUrlMagic; */
//body of script is here in one line    
// X-HAProxy-Expires: Thu, 3 Oct 2004 09:41:38 +0000 
/script>
```

After investigating the page more via net of firebug I found there are actually 3 scripts that are fetched [http:// is removed]:

```
cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/loaders/1499/l.js?aoi=1311798366&pid=1499&zoneid=309980&ext=saveshare
i.74055djs.info/opt_1380719488847/opt_content.js?partner=74055d&channel=74055dp952&appTitle=
v.zilionfast.in/2663516195/?t=vrt
```

I searched all of the scripts and project for these url's and many subsets of them but nothing found. The main scripts of my application are as follows:

```
bootstrap/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css 
bootstrap-responsive-rtl.min.css 
font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
uniform.default.css
style-metro-rtl.css
style-rtl.css
style-responsive-rtl.css
default-rtl.css
jquery-1.10.1.min.js
jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js 
bootstrap/js/bootstrap-rtl.min.js
bootstrap-hover-dropdown/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js

jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js
jquery.blockui.min.js
jquery.cookie.min.js
jquery.uniform.min.js
app.js - which is the main js of the application
```

The point is one of these scripts - the one www[dot]dealply[dot]com is some sort of deals site which made me think it's some sort of hidden linking for page ranking.

I'm not an advanced JS coder and so please help me solve the problem

Thanks

Comment: Do you think that the code is hidden in the template?

Comment: Delete it and see if everything still works as expected. If so, that's your solution.

Comment: @remyabel Yes that what I think

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia The problem is, the script is generated on the fly and I assumed that some other js function is calling it, so there is no way to delete it even if everything works fine afterwards

Comment: Try loading one script at a time to see what offending script is calling the code.

Comment: I would say it's `app.js` anyway, if so, you'll need to dig into that: search for the url injected in that code and try to deal with it, although it might be hard if it's minimized.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia I think you're right, because I deleted every 3rd party script and styles as "remyable" said but they appear until I delete App.Init() of the app.js and now I'm digging it. hopefully it's not minified as I bought the product - some hint on copyright :)

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia It's a little weird, I deleted every script and styles in my app - app.js also - and it's just an unstyled html but those scripts still appears! Am I missing something here? Is it possible that these links are comming from some addons! The funny part is I also see these links in NET of firebug of stackoverflow.com

Comment: If you bought the product, hopefully it's minified since that's the proper way to include javascript. However, also hopefully they include the source code somewhere. Now you need to find where App.Init() is defined and keep digging. Or contact the seller, they might be more helpful since they created the code.

Comment: I think I found the problem - from this fact that the exact same script is fetched in many sites beside my local one that there is an add-on named "soavenSShaRe 5.10" makes this scripts to come. I'm not definitly sure but i found under this link that it's a malware http://camas.comodo.com/cgi-bin/submit?file=6462127166fc58f6de565639daac5d71964f4e590e7b43f9da484a69d8b3134e . now after removing it, everything seems peaceful :)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have a backup of your template.

Delete the scripts completely and see if it still works(Proposed by Francisco Presencia in commets), if so then your done. Pretty sure from what you have shown us it should work.

If the template fails after you delete the scripts then restore the template and contact the author, it's an external scripts so there isn't a way you can modify it if it affects your template.

Comment: thanks @gander7 for your reply. bu as I stated in comments above my problem - and maybe many other's - was from a add-on named "soavenSShaRe 5.10" which is a malware and injects that script. so by removing that add-on and associated files the problem has solved

Comment: Awesome, 
I didn't expand the comments :P